# Prevent mv from moving target folder

Tags: directory, symlink, mv

If symbolic link `bar` points to folder `foo`, then the two following commands have very different behaviors:

```
mv bar  baz   # rename link 'bar' to 'baz'
mv bar/ baz   # rename folder 'foo' to 'baz'
```

(tried with bash 3.2 and zsh 5.7.1 on OSX).

I find the second behavior very dangerous (especially given that "tab" usually completes folder names with a trailing slash), and would like to prevent it if possible. The manual of `mv` doesn't seem to have an option for that. Short of aliasing `mv` with my own function, is there maybe a Bash option or zsh option, or something else, that would help with this issue?

Comment: This comment will be useless but Linux coreutils mv doesn't have this issue:
`mv bar/ baz -> mv: cannot move 'bar/' to 'baz': Not a directory`

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Good to know! Weirdly enough though, `gmv` (installed via `brew install coreutils`) has the same issue on my side.

Comment: one way in Bash might be `set mark-directories off` in a `INPUTRC` file, but that setting applies to all directories, not just symlinks

Comment: Maybe bash 3.2 is a bit too dated? I see it is from 2006. Not much helpful, but for the slash in autocomplete, you may disable it if your bash has `mark-symlinked-directories` option (look in `man bash`, "Readline Variables" section).

Comment: @Quasímodo unfortunately in a compspec context that setting is ignored, at least in OSX's bash3.2

Comment: The difference between OSes is down to the behavior of the `rename` system call, and this looks like a bug in Linux's `rename`. Why would `rename("bar/", "baz")` fail with ENOTDIR? It's supposed to be equivalent to `rename("foo", "baz")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In zsh, as long as you don't [`unsetopt auto_remove_slash`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-AUTO_005fREMOVE_005fSLASH), zsh removes the trailing slash at the end of completion. It adds a slash during completion, so that `ba`<kbd>Tab</kbd> results in `bar/`, but if you press <kbd>Space</kbd> (or move the cursor or most anything other than inserting something), zsh removes the `/`. (The `/` is highlighted to indicate that it's “on sufferance”.)

If you end up entering the command with a slash `mv bar/ baz`, renaming the directory `foo` is the expected behavior. Since `bar/` ends with a slash, pathname resolution converts it to `foo`.

If you want to avoid this behavior, you'll have to write a wrapper function for `mv`. Untested, for zsh:

```
function mv {
  local i
  for ((i=1; i < $#; i++)); do
    if [[ $argv[$i] == *[^/]*/ ]]; then
      argv[$i]=${argv[i]%/}
    fi
  done
  command mv "$@"
}
```

Note that this function is fairly naive, for example it doesn't understand that `-t`/`--target` takes a destination as argument which shouldn't have its trailing slash stripped.

Comment: Thanks for that Gilles! I just disabled `auto_remove_slash` to avoid adverse effects with `rsync`, where trailing slash are actually meaningful; so that option is no good in my case, but might be helpful to others. It looks like the function you provided is a good place to start for an alias.

Comment: I think you can override the effect of `auto_remove_slash` for a specific command with the appropriate `zstyle`. I don't know what the incantation is without research.